# Mortin Myes' is at it again! 'HOW TO READ.'

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Mortin Myes' has blasted back onto the minimalist art scene with a painting titled 'HOW TO READ.'
Modern art critics from around the world are puzzling over the meaning of this abstract work, and how on earth it got it's title.

Care to teach them a thing or two?

[image]

Comment: A, another painting I need to acquire for the gallery of [hyper-modern art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyper-modern%20is%3Aquestion)! I like it :c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to read?

> Between the lines, sort of.
>
>  The "maze" is arranged in a grid. There aren't any lines around the perimeter and there are no horizontal strokes in every third row. That looks as if the maze described four rows of letters.
>
>  And it does: Cross every wall segment with a perpendicular stroke so that the original and new segments form a plus. Then look at the the new segments: They form a message.

The message is:

> [image: Twist each segment :)]

Comment: Note that the message actually gives another description of the procedure you just followed.

Comment: Yes, of course, but what good are instructions that you receive only after the procedure?

Comment: You'll have to ask Mortin that one, I'm afraid.